# nodejs request using agent proxy via gimmeproxy.com

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I want to make GET request to scrape some data thru a proxy server that is randomly generated using the gimmeproxy.com free API.

I am able to get the proxy ip/port and am using
'https-proxy-agent' to setup the agent with the proxy data.

Whenever I try to call any website I always get

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>405 Method Not Allowed</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Method Not Allowed</h1>
<p>The requested method CONNECT is not allowed for the URL 
/index.html.en.backup.</p>
</body></html>
```

Here is my node script:

```js
const request = require('request'), HttpsProxyAgent = require('https-proxy-agent');

generateRandomProxy(function(proxy){
    var agent = new HttpsProxyAgent({
        proxyHost: proxy.proxyHost,
        proxyPort: proxy.proxyPort
    });
    request({
        uri: "http://example.com",
        method: "GET",
        agent: agent,
        timeout: 5000,
    }, function(error, response, body) {
        console.log(body);
    });       
})

function generateRandomProxy(cb){
    request.get(' https://gimmeproxy.com/api/getProxy?get=true&cookies=true&country=US',{json:true},function(err,res){
        if(!err){cb({
            proxyHost: res.body.ip, 
            proxyPort: res.body.port
        })}
        else{console.log('problem obtaining proxy')}
    })
}
```

So my question: How can I route my request thru the proxy and then get a returned body that is valid?

As you see now I keep getting the **405 Method Not Allowed**

Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Just found some GimmeProxy wrapper for Node.js: [gimmeproxy-request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gimmeproxy-request).

It claims to automatically re-route requests through another proxy when one fails.

With this module code would look like this:

```js
const setup = require('gimmeproxy-request').setup;
const request = require('gimmeproxy-request').request;
 
setup({
  api_key: 'your api key',
  query: 'get=true&cookies=true&country=US&supportsHttps=true&maxCheckPeriod=1800&minSpeed=10', // additional gimmeproxy query parameters
  retries: 5, // max retries before fail
  test: (body, response) => body.indexOf('captcha') === -1 && response.statusCode === 200 // test function
});
 
request('https://example.com', {
  timeout: 10000 // additional request parameters, see https://github.com/request/request
},
function(err, res, body) {
  console.log('err', err)
  console.log('res', res)
  console.log('body', body)
  process.exit()
});
```

---

I guess the issue is that you sometimes get not an https proxy from Gimmeproxy, while 'https-proxy-agent' expects https proxy only.

To fix it, use the [proxy-agent](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-proxy-agent) package of the same author and pass **curl** field of GimmeProxy response. It will select correct proxy agent implementation.

The following code works for me:

```js
const request = require('request'), ProxyAgent = require('proxy-agent');

generateRandomProxy(function(proxy){
    console.log(proxy);
    var agent = new ProxyAgent(proxy.curl);
    request({
        uri: "https://example.com",
        method: "GET",
        agent: agent,
        timeout: 5000,
    }, function(error, response, body) {
        console.log(error);
        console.log(body);
    });       
})

function generateRandomProxy(cb){
    request.get('https://gimmeproxy.com/api/getProxy?get=true&cookies=true&country=US&supportsHttps=true&maxCheckPeriod=1800&minSpeed=10',{json:true},function(err,res){
        if(!err){cb(res.body)}
        else{console.log('problem obtaining proxy')}
    })
}
```

**Note**: If you want to call https websites, you should query for proxies with https support using **supportsHttps=true** parameter. Also it makes sense to query for fresh proxies with **maxCheckPeriod=1800** parameter. Setting **minSpeed=10** also helps:

https://gimmeproxy.com/api/getProxy?get=true&cookies=true&country=US&supportsHttps=true&maxCheckPeriod=1800&minSpeed=10

Comment: Thanks for the extra parameters. I am still getting same error message 405 Method Not Allowed

Comment: Did you try the code I provided (with https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-proxy-agent) ? Just checked and seems to be working fine for me.